# Rails 3 - Database query on Models User and Role in a many to many condition

Tags: ruby, ruby-on-rails-3, activerecord, devise, cancan

I have two entities. User and Role. I am using Devise and CanCan.
They are in a many to many relationship.

User has a lot of roles. 
One of the roles is "Administrator". I verify if my user is an administrator using:

```
if (user.role? :administrator) .... #this is already implemented and working
```

I have to validate that never exists more than 2 administrator in the same department on the system. For that purpose I created a custom validate method:

```
class User < ActiveRecord::Base
    validate :maximum_numbers_of_admins if self.role? :administrator
    belongs_to :department

    def maximum_numbers_of_admins
        #Some code here
    end
```

In that method I should count the number of Users that have role administrator (without counting myself).
I don't know how to set the :conditions of my find method to get this number.

This is the specification of the Role class:

```
# == Schema Information
#
# Table name: roles
#
#  id         :integer         not null, primary key
#  name       :string(255)
#  created_at :datetime
#  updated_at :datetime
#
```

There is a many to many relationship between users and Roles. (Table roles_users)
Any help with that?

Thanks

Comment: con you post the Role fields please?

Comment: yeah I guessed it was name. My answer should do the trick.

Comment: I commented your answer below.

Comment: Hi Tony from Role table definition you can't have a many to many relation with User model you lack the user_id field

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It could be something along this lines:

```
def maximum_numbers_of_admins
    if Role.find(:conditions => ['name = ?', 'Administrator']).users.count < 2
      return true
    else
      return false
    end
end
```

Comment: Let me try this. But I should exclude myself from that users list.
This is because if I am updating my model I do not want the error to fire (there are 2 already but one of them is myself).

Comment: How can I filter it without having to iterate through all users?

Comment: Moreover, the users that I should filter have to be in the same department as me. User belongs to department.

Comment: Hi Tony you can avoid iterating through all users only if you set up some role counters but you are expanding your question.

Comment: Yes, I expanding because I didn't realized it at first. Sorry.

Comment: Notice that Role.find(:conditions => ['name = ?', 'Administrator']) is a collection and it does not have the users method